# How can Xcode 6 adaptive UIs be backwards-compatible with iOS 7 and iOS 6?

Tags: xcode6, adaptive-ui

I just  watched the WWDC video #216, "Building Adaptive UI with UIKit."

At about 45:10 Tony Ricciardi talks about changes to IB in Xcode 6 to support the new changes.

He says "You can deploy these documents backwards to older versions of iOS".

(where "These documents" presumably means XIBs and storyboards that have specific settings for different size classes.)

I'm not making this up. Go watch the WWDC video.

How is that possible? Trait collections and size classes are only defined in iOS 8. How can runtime behavior that's dependent on UI constructs that are new to iOS 8 work in previous iOS versions?

If it **is** possible it would be wonderful. You could build apps that will run on iOS 6, 7, and 8, and take advantage of the new flexible UI layout abilities that Apple has added to Xcode 6. I've created adaptive UI logic myself in code, and it's quite a bit of work.

Comment: [There is also a document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1) now from Apple that describes compatibility with versions < 8

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Changes made to the UI with Size Classes in Interface Builder DO appear correctly on iOS 7 devices and the Preview in Xcode. For example, I changed some Auto Layout constraints and font sizes for Regular height Regular width and those changed constraints are visible in the iPad Simulator running iOS 7.0.

All size class optimizations are made available to iOS 7, except size classes that have a Compact Height. This has been confirmed by Apple and is now stated directly in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1):

**For apps supporting versions of iOS earlier than iOS 8, most size classes are backward compatible.


Size classes are backward compatible when:

- The app is built using Xcode version 6 or later

- The deployment target of the app is earlier than iOS 8

- Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib

- The value of the height component is not compact**

Because iOS 7 doesn't respect a couple of size classes, if you use them you'll run into issues. For example:
When you have Compact w Any h defined and then Compact w Compact h defined, on iOS 7 it will respect the Compact w Any h but on iOS 8 it renders the Compact w Compact h appearance.

So, if you would like to utilize those two size classes and maintain compatibility with iOS 7, I would do any optimizations you desire for iPhone in landscape in Any w Any h or Compact w Any h, then perform your other optimizations for different size classes as necessary, and that way you won't need to use any size class with compact height and will avoid running into issues.

Comment: I can confirm that in Beta4, the Compact/Compact size class is not respected in the simulator or on an iOS 7 device. Interesting that some size classes are respected though. Thanks for testing.

Comment: Testing for Regular/Regular on a device and it doesn't NOT respond to size class customizations, all I get is Any/Any with Beta 7

Comment: @hokiewalrus I just checked with Xcode 6 beta 7 and get the exact same results I detailed in the answer. Changing the width of the box in IB for  Regular Regular does show correctly on iPad running iOS 7.1.

Comment: @Joey Hmm, neither the simulator or the physical device responds to size classes with 7.1 for me. Hopefully it's just a bug with my install of beta 7 and it'll be fixed with a GM release.

Comment: Damn, so not really that backwards compatible :( Any good news from the GM?

Comment: Situation remains unchanged in Xcode 6 GM, see updated answer.

Comment: @Joey this is not a bug; this is intentional. `Compact-Compact` is not exported for iOS 7; `Compact-Regular` is. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, the answer above is misleading.

Comment: This is hilarious. Compact height is literally the only useful size class for dealing with tiny iPhone 4 and below

Comment: Any/Any is also not working for iPhone landscape in IOS7.. I made compactW/RegularH for portrait and Any/Any for other but dosnt work  :/

Comment: confirm, this is not compatible with ios 7 even using the trick mentioned in the end

Answer (score 68):

When deploying your app to iOS 7, Xcode will compile your storyboard in two different ways:

- For iPhone, your storyboard gets compiled as "Compact-Regular" (Compact width, regular height), and this gets packaged as your "~iphone" nib.
- For iPad, your storyboard gets compiled as "Regular-Regular" and gets packaged as your "~ipad" nib.

So if you're looking to deploy to both iOS 7 and iOS 8, you should focus your design on the Compact-Any and Regular-Any size classes. That will give you the best experience in terms of matching the UI across deployment targets. You are, of course, welcome to modify the layout for other size classes, but unless those modifications would get applied to the Compact-Regular or Regular-Regular size classes, then you would not see those modifications on iOS 7.

Comment: My understanding of your answer is that "Regular-Regular" should work in iPad iOS7. But it is not working. I have tested in XCode6 GM release. Please correct me If I had misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: It seems that regular-regular only work on storyboard, not xib

Comment: @BorisCharpentier I have reported a bug about that [rdar://18737656](http://openradar.appspot.com/18737656), that was closed as duplicate of opened #18490866

Comment: @BorisCharpentier did you find any solution for xib ?

Comment: @saadnib I'm switching to full storyboard.

Comment: @BorisCharpentier, i just found that this issue has been resolved in XCode 6.1.1 :-)

Answer (score 27):

**Note: This answer was relevant to a beta version of Xcode 6 and is no longer applicable to the shipping version. See answers by [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976792/1467918) and [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795533/1467918) on this page for proper information.**

**(original answer retained below):**

---

While `Storyboards/XIBs` configured to use size classes will run on `iOS 7`, the OS does not currently respect those `size classes` and appears to use the default 'Any/Any' size class.

I agree that the particular slide you are referring to seems to promise such compatibility, but it doesn't appear to be the case currently `(Xcode 6 beta 2)`.

To test, I created a project `(iOS 8 SDK, deployment target of 7.1)` with a single button that is centered `vertically and horizontally` in the Any/Any size class, but aligned to the top left corner in the Compact/Compact size class (e.g. iPhone in landscape). Xcode's Preview Assistant shows that the button changes its position in `iOS 8`, but not `iOS 7`. I confirmed this behavior on an `iOS 7` device as well.

Comment: Roy, thanks for replying. I haven't had the time yet to test this myself, and I appreciate it. The presenter in that video should have been clearer. I think he must have meant that the XIB/Storyboard files can be read by iOS 6 and 7, but without support for adaptive UI. It makes coding for apps that run on iOS < 8 problematic.

Comment: Indeed. I wonder if there is any official documentation on how to support the newer size classes and the older orientation/idiom approach in the same Storyboard/XIB. I'll update the answer if I find anything.

Comment: In my experience, Apple seems to think that older OS versions cease to exist as soon as they announce a new version. In fact, the engineering team seems to stop paying attention to a new OS version as soon as it's released, and start focusing all their energies on the next major version. I have NEVER had a bug I submitted fixed in the current major release. They

Comment: This no longer appears to be the case with Xcode 6 beta 4. See the answer I just added.

Comment: This really should not be the accepted answer, it is not correct information. All size class optimizations made in Storyboards are respected on iOS 7, except those for compact height size classes.

Comment: @Joey thanks for the heads up; I've edited my answer to refer readers to your answer, as well as Dave's.

Answer (score 12):

As some of the answers and comments were discussing the nature of backwards-compatibility, I thought I would share an excerpt direct from the **[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1)**:

~~~~~

## Deploying an App With Size Classes on Earlier iOS Versions

**For apps supporting versions of iOS earlier than iOS 8, most size classes are backward compatible.**

Size classes are backward compatible when:

- The app is built using Xcode version 6 or later
- The deployment target of the app is earlier than iOS 8
- Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib
- **The value of the height component is not compact**

~~~~~
That last bullet point is targeted at this discussion, where Apple confirms that **as long as "compact height" is *not* used**, it should maintain backwards-compatibility.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It's great this is now documented, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 3):

While dealing with the similar issue I found another answer that I haven't seen here yet. Looks like Size Classes in `XIB` files are not working at all. If I create cell prototype in the `storyboard` file it works in iOS7 as explained in other answers, however when the same prototype cell is moved into separate `XIB` file - size classes are ignored in iOS7.

Here is link to the sample project demonstrating this behavior: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6402890/testSizeClasses.zip

In the prototype cell I have four constraints from each edge of the grey view. Each of the is configured in a same way: Any/Any - 10, Regular/Regular - 20

[image]

It works fine in iOS8 simulator for both XIB and Storyboard, and in iOS7 only cells defined in Storyboard gets updated constraints on iPad:

[image]

Comment: $^%$^%@#^&@#%&^% ... and here I am with lots of xib files and deploying on iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: Exactly. I was combining iPhone and iPad storyboards into one and thought that separating cells into their own XIB file would help :). I would appreciate if you can +1 my answer.

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If it saves anyone time, I *believe* that the way Xcode 6 provides quasi-backwards compatibility for size classes is via the historical `~ipad` and `~iphone` suffixed storyboards, and nothing more. This makes sense since size classes are a more abstracted way of how we previously defined an iPad storyboard, and an iPhone storyboard.

Therefore:

- If your goal is to use size classes to support device family specific layouts (iPad vs. iPhone), then you are in luck: size classes are a nicer interface to the previously supported method.
- If your goal is to use size classes to support altered layouts for different models within the *same* device family - ie. iPhone 5/6/6+ inc. landscape, then you are *out of luck*. Using these would require a minimum iOS 8 deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

@lducool - In interface builder, in the Identity inspector, change 'Builds For' to iOS7.1 and later.

Comment: No difference in output.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answers from Dave and Joey do not work for me.
I am not allowed to comment in this thread, so please forgive me if this is the wrong place.

I have made up a specific question for that:
[Example for iPhone portrait landscape adaptive UI which is backwards-compatible with iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694627/example-for-iphone-portrait-landscape-adaptive-ui-which-is-backwards-compatible)

From what I learned so far, I believe now that, like in my example, is is not possible to have 2 separate, different constraints for one ui element in portrait and landscape mode with iPhone iOS7 based on size classes.
Would be glad if I am mistaken, though.