# Size Class "Any Width | Compact Height" not reflected on iPhones with iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Really simple to reproduce. In XCode 6 GM change the size class to "Any Width | Compact Height" and add a uiview and change the color. Then open the assistant editor and add a view for iphone 5 ios8 and ios7. The UIView is not visible on the ios7 iphone.

Am I insane thinking that "Any Width | Compact Height" should work for iphone5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Apple documentation, "size classes are backward compatible when:" and "the value of the height component is not compact". Since you have set Compact Height, you're not backward compatible to iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend you to start with ANY W ANY H, this is the base value for all size classes. Once you have done it, then go to the specific size classes, if you feel anything wrong, you can disable some constrains. These constraints won't apply to your current layout but still work for others. You can add some new constraints and new constraints work at current size class.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentioned in [How can Xcode 6 adaptive UIs be backwards-compatible with iOS 7 and iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795533/3829264), iPhone storyboards are compiled for iOS7 as "Compact Width | Regular Height", but you use "Any Width | Compact Height", which doesn't match. Try "Compact Width | Any Height".

Comment: "Compact Width | Any Height" does not work in my preview for iOS 7. "Compact Width | Regular Height" though does. Is this an issue or should "Compact Width | Any Height" not work in iOS. I thought only "Compact Height" was an issue...

Comment: I guess my issue was rather with the constraints set and not with the siezClasses...