# Using size classes, auto layout and build for iOS7 in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

Is there a way to use Interface Builder to maximize a view for the w:Any h:Any size classes without relying on iOS8 only features?

I'm trying to have a simple scrollview inside a navigation controller and a tab bar with some horizontal centered labels. But I can't even get the scrollview to be maximized without getting `layout attributes relative to the layout margin` or `misplaced view` warnings.

I dragged the scrollview across the canvas between navigation bar and tab bar.
I set contraints of the scrollview to center alignment Y and X and vertical space at the top to take in account of the navigationbar.

Now when I try to add a contraint to have the bottom next to the navigationbar I get the iOS 8.0 warning.

Also I don't understand what width and height I need to set when I want the object to be dynamically maximized depending on the device or orientation - I thought that was the point of auto layout.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24976792/1292061) might be relevant.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you've found an answer, be sure to come back here and answer your own question so that the next person who comes looking can see what you figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Riley pointed out this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976792/1292061) helped me to get started.

Also specifically to my scrollview problem I needed to make the following constraints:

vertical space top and bottom, horizontal space left and right, center x alignment and most importantly don't use the checkbox "constrain to margin" which is only available for iOS8+.