# Example for iPhone portrait landscape adaptive UI which is backwards-compatible with iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode6, adaptive-ui

I have read this thread
[How can Xcode 6 adaptive UIs be backwards-compatible with iOS 7 and iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172860/how-can-xcode-6-adaptive-uis-be-backwards-compatible-with-ios-7-and-ios-6)

and especially the answers from Dave and Joey.

Still I am having a hard time getting a simple example to work:
xcode 6, size classes enabled, iPhone iOS 7, uibutton width 100 on portrait mode, width 400 on landscape mode. And say width 600 on iPad.

I just can't get this to work. I tried different combinations of setting width constraint, but either the button width is 100 in both orientation modes, or 400, but never different.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a guide, which constraints have to be set on which size class to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you fix this? I try to use the new size classes in iPhone  but works great just in iOS 8. In iOS 7 or 6 load Compact/Regular for Portrait but when I change the orientation to Landscape, still continues with this and does not change to Compact Width-Any Height.

Comment: It seems like Apple does'nt want backward compatibility with size classes :/

Answer (score 3):

For iPhone, [Deploying an App With Size Classes on Earlier iOS Versions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1) said that the value of the height component should not be compact for earlier version. But in [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LayoutandAppearance.html), the landscape mode of iPhone is Compact height and Compact Width, which means that iPhone landscape mode of size classes will not work for earlier version.

Comment: Yes, I have read the statement about the compact height too. But the answers from Dave and Joey in the thread I referenced made me think there is a working solution for my simple iPhone Portrait/Landscape mode problem with iOS7 and size classes. If it is not possible, this would also be an answer, but I am still hoping someone can give a solution to this small example. Thanks