# Size Classes in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, xcode, size-classes

I created a new app in Xcode 6 using Size Classes.  After testing with iOS 7, I can't figure out how to get iPhone to display a certain size class while in landscape mode.

I first developed the UI with iPhone landscape as wAny hCompact, but iOS 7 doesn't recognize that.  I had iPhone portrait in wAny hAny.

I then changed it so now I'm using wCompact hRegular for iPhone portrait.  I then modified wAny hAny to be the landscape layout.  But it's not using that layout when the iOS 7 device is in landscape.

Is iOS 7 able to use different size classes based on the device being portrait or landscape?  If so, which size class should I be using?

Reference:  [Really helpful information about backwards compatibility with size classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172860/how-can-xcode-6-adaptive-uis-be-backwards-compatible-with-ios-7-and-ios-6/25795533#25795533)

ps.  I'm not concerned with iPad because the device does not display a different size class based on the device rotation in iOS 8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Size classes works in iOS 7 for sure. But only if you follow several rules:

- The app is built using Xcode version **6** or later
- The deployment target of the app is **earlier than iOS 8**
- Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib file
- The value of the height component is not compact (**yep, this is your case, it's not possible in iOS 7, unfortunatelly**)

There is a little explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976792/2190175

Comment: Bullet point 3 is incorrect --  xibs ARE supported: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1

Comment: @Austen edited it. Now point 3 is correct : "Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib file"

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Size classes are really supported in xibs for iOS 7.0 too,  starting from XCode 6.1.1. But limitations on backwards compatibility is still apply.

Answer (score 0):

No I'm afraid that Size Classes were introduced in iOS 8. You could write some conditional code to run on iOS to determine the screen/view size/orientation and change the the layout that way when iOS 8 becomes your minimum target the conditional code can be removed.

Comment: I suppose I didn't say it, but I was referring to the backwards compatibility of size classes.  For my project I did end up making iOS 8 the minimum supported version.  
As a sidenote, I found this [link](http://swiftiostutorials.com/backward-compatibility-ios-size-classes/) just now talking about what I believe was my issue above.