# Size classes support iphone landscape in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, size-classes

[image]What size class Should i use for iOS 7 Landscape mode, since compact height layouts are not supported in iOS 7?

Should i also support the regular height orientation, but it doesnt have a regular orientation for iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking to do is possible.  I asked a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707300/size-classes-in-ios-7) and had a good answer, however the answer was that it's not really doable.  Personally I left 7.0 behind.