# Change Autolayout constraint for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, autolayout

Hi I have created a popup view and have added a view's leading,trailing,top and bottom spacing say 5 px, not my view looks good in iPhone.

But for iPad, behaviour is same and it is setting same 5 px for all spacing, now i for iPad it need to increase that spacing so my view will become some smaller and fit in centre.

Is that possible without code? I added all autolayout constraint through XIB.

[image]

Comment: Use size class to change contraint for ipad

Comment: Deployment target is iOS 7.

Comment: one other way to remove leading and trailing. add width and center x constraint... then change width constraint programmtically

Comment: @PJR : you can use size classes in ios 7 also under several conditions. check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707300/size-classes-in-ios-7)

Comment: the _size classes_ have been created for just such reason.

Answer (score 2):

Yes PJR. You can do this using the size classes.  Change the WAny hAny to wRegular hRegular in your storyboard. And now update the required constants values. Whatever the changes u made in wRegular hRegular will be only applicable for iPad. Hope this helps

[image].

Answer (score 0):

just set horizontally in container (center X)  and vertically in container constraint (center Y) and width and height constant