# Xcode 6.1 Interface Builder not showing elements according to device type

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, size-classes

Last night I was working with size classes in Interface Builder. I created a new xib file and added two button with title "iPhone" and "iPad". The intention was "iPhone" button should visible on all iPhone devices and "iPad" button on all iPad devices.

Everything was fine, it was showing on all devices expected result.

But the problem was **on iPad 2 (iOS 7.0.4) the button with title "iPhone" was showing.**
I have tested on following devices which were showing correct result.

**Devices:**

1)iPhone 3, 4 and 5.

2)iPad 2 (iOS 8.1.1)

**For that I have followed following steps:**

1) Created new view controller file with xib.(File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Set "Subclass of:" as (for example) UIViewController and check "Also create XIB file".)

2) Changed the Interface Builder pane to "wConpact hRegular".

3) Added button with title "iPhone" and constraint as it should look horizontally center and from top 150px.

4) Changed the Interface Builder pane to "wRegular hRegular".

5) Added button with title "iPad" and constraint as it should look horizontally center and from top 150px.

I am using:

**Xcode : 6.1**

**Based SDK: 8.1**

**Deployment Target: 6.1**

**Device : Universal**

**Use Auto Layout : Checked**

**Use Size Classes : Checked**

Result Screenshots:

1st) iPhone 5s

2nd) iPad 2 (iOS 8.1.1)

3rd) iPad 2 (iOS 7.0.4)

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPad 2 (iOS 8.1.1)]

[image: iPad 2 (iOS 7.0.4)]

**Important thing is there is no problem if I use Storyboard to design.**
**I dont understand why this is happening? Is there any property which I am missing or its iOS bug.**

Please Suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172860/how-can-xcode-6-adaptive-uis-be-backwards-compatible-with-ios-7-and-ios-6)

Comment: @Raptor...thanks for sharing this important link. This will help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6 and 7 do not support Size Classes of Adaptive Layout, it will use the default 'Any/Any' size classes.

In your case, the storyboard thinks the default size class has a button with "iPhone" on it, therefore iPad with iOS 7 will display the iPhone version.

Comment: @Raptor...thanks for quick reply. But problem is that it is running fine in storyboard and not in xib.

Comment: Clarification needed: What's in your Storyboard now?

Comment: Same contents as my xib containing, only the name of view controller is different.

Answer (score 0):

As per 'Dave DeLong' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795533/1228371), I am going to follow this

When deploying app to iOS 7, Xcode compiles storyboard in two ways:

1) For iPhone, storyboard gets compiled as "Compact width, regular height"

2) For iPad, storyboard gets compiled as "wRegular-hRegular"