# UITableview Cell height not working in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788390/dynamic-uilabel-size-ios-7-issue) SO question. 
my `UITableViewCell Height` perfect working on `IOS8`. Problem With `IOS7` hight is increase but content is not display.

my code is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
long hightmain=0;

    if(selectIndex && indexPath.section == selectIndex.section)
    {

        NSString * myString = [description_vegetable_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        CGSize labelSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(190, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        hightmain=labelSize.height+120;

        if (hightmain<=140)
        {
             btn11.frame=CGRectMake(240,100,70,17);
             Description_LBL.frame=CGRectMake(127, 0, 190, 140);
             BGImage.frame=CGRectMake(0, -3, 320, 140);
        }
        else
        {                               
            [btn11 setTitle:@"Less Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn11.frame=CGRectMake(240,hightmain-30,70,17);
            Description_LBL.frame=CGRectMake(127, -20, 190, hightmain);
            BGImage.frame=CGRectMake(0, -3, 320, hightmain);
            return hightmain;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 140;
    }
}
```

`Description_LBL.frame=CGRectMake(127, 0, 190, 140);` my label height increases but text not display ....in IOS8 complete working but IOS7 in not working

Comment: You're using storyboards and auto layout?

Comment: no . i am using xib and auto layout is off

Comment: Do you return nothing if (hightmain<=140)

Comment: I'm not sure if this has to do with your problem but 
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: is deprecated since iOS7, be careful

Comment: Are you reloading the tableView when selecting a row?, heightForRowAtIndexPath get called only on populating the table or scrolling through the table.

Comment: @JayBhalani the code is working in iOS8 right.

Comment: yes  but problem with IOS7 @Sam

Comment: @JayBhalani Can you just try to print the hightmain inside and check whether the problem is showing up for certain height[iOS7].also one more thing  if (hightmain<=140) in that case you are still not returning anything[may not be the reason]

Comment: Description_LBL.frame=CGRectMake(127, 0, 190, 140); my label height increases but text not display ....in IOS8 complete working but IOS7 in not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `boundingRectWithSize:` which NSString public methods that calculate the size based on a string value.

Example

```
[testString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]} context:nil]
```

Note: 
sizeWithFont: Deprecated in iOS 7.0