# UITableview heightForRowAtIndexPath: reloads label in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell with 3 labels and one button. Everything worked well until I didn't implement `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method for my table view. (I need it because I set the cell height here based on the length of the labels.) The problem is when I tap `likeButton` the `likeCountLabel.text` will display the labels sample value from the IB for a sec and then shows the previous (correct) string again in every cell, not just in the tapped. When I remove `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` it's perfect again. As I discovered it happens after I reload the table view, but don't have any idea, because these labels work perfectly when I don't adjust the height.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFQuery *query = [like query];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (objects) {

            NSString *likeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", objects.count];
            cell.likeCountLabel.text = likeNumber;

        }
    }];

    cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapLikeButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    cell.usrName.text = object[@"usrName"];
    cell.usrDescription.text = object[@"desc"];
    cell.date.text = object[@"date"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.usrName.text = object[@"usrName"];
    cell.usrDescription.text = object[@"desc"];
    cell.date.text = object[@"date"];

    //get the height the cell
    //  [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    //paddign of 1 Point
    return height + 12;
}

- (void)didTapLikeButton:(id)sender {

    // Cast Sender to UIButton
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    PFObject *likeRow = [self.objects objectAtIndex:button.tag];
              [SaveHelper likeObject:likeRow withUploader:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't dequeue or instantiate cells in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` - this breaks up the pattern (ie: `tableView` asks for needed height of cell at certain `indexPath` and you on the other hand ask it to instantiate a cell for the very same `indexPath` so you could answer about needed height...)

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` a cell is generated (or reused) and filled with data according to the data model. If a cells height depends on the data - this height should be calculated from the data model, too.

To avoid instantiating cells in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you could write up a [class method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053646/653513) like `+ (CGFloat) heightOfCellWithContent...` and use this method to calculate needed height of certain type of cell within the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

In other words: you need `NewsTableViewCell` **class** to be able to tell you what height would its **instance** (a cell of that type) need with certain content...

EDIT:

You obviously have a `UITableViewCell` subclass named `NewsTableViewCell` and instances of this class expect to be filled with data like `usrName`, `usrDescription`...

Add a class method to `NewsTableViewCell`:

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightNeededForUsrName:(NSString *)usrName
                       usrDescription:(NSString *)usrDescription {
  // calculate the height here
}
```

or even better in your case:

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightNeededForData:(PFObject *)data {
  // calculate the height here
}
```

And then modify your `- (CGFloat)tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in this manner:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return [NewsTableViewCell cellHeightNeededForData:object];
}
```

Comment: Could you give a little more guidance, should I use the custom cell in the class method? Or what should I use from my existing code in the method?

Comment: Thanks! I just tried to create an ivar for the cell and use it like self.cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` but doesn't helped.

Comment: Hope this helps: if not i'll return to your question tomorrow (it's kind of late here...)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I would really appreciate it. I've tried what you recommended, but couldn't reproduce this value `CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;` inside the class method so I couldn't run it. I understand the concept, but don't know how could calculate the size properly.

Comment: I missed the part that you are using autolayout: this makes it a bit more complicated - but still managable. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28514006) should help you getting things in order.