# iOS: Size Class for iPad not showing uiviews on iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, size-classes

I'm building an iPad application on landscape orientation on xcode 6.

I used size class

> (hRegular wRegular)

.. And **it looks good on iPad with iOS8** ..But when i ran it on iPad with iOS 7.1 .. The views is just not appearing.
I tried to target even

> (hRegual wAny)

but it's the same.. 
The funny thing that the only size class accepted by iPad on iOS7 is (hAny wAny)

Hope that anyone can help me in this.

============================
Update

here is an example project for what I mean 
[iPad Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RNyCg4CmhFR193YlY1REVGVGM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

When deploying an Application With Size Classes on earlier iOS versions; most size classes are backward compatible.

Following are the key points when using Size classes:

- The app is built using Xcode version 6 or later
- The deployment target of the app is earlier than iOS 8
- Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib
- The value of the height component is not compact

For more information on this subject, Check out this  [Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172860/how-can-xcode-6-adaptive-uis-be-backwards-compatible-with-ios-7-and-ios-6)

Comment: yeah that all set already .. but that's not what I asked for .. thanks for your answer :)